# Smoothing signal - convolution

Tags: python, filtering, convolution

I have an iterative model in Python which generates at signal using a function which contains a derivative. As the model iterates the signal becomes noisy - I suspect it may be an issue with computing the numerical derivative.  I've tried to smooth this by applying a low-pass filter, convolving the noisy signal with a Gaussian kernel.  I use the code snippet:

```
nw = 256
std = 40
window = gaussian(nw, std, sym=True)
filtered = convolve(current, window, mode='same') / np.sum(window)
```

where `current` is my signal, and `gaussian` and `convolve` have been imported from scipy.  This seems to give a slight improvement, and the first 2 or 3 iterations appear very smooth.  However, after that the signal becomes extremely noisy again, despite the fact that the low-pass filter is positioned inside the iterative loop.

Can anyone suggest where I might be going wrong or how I could better tackle this problem?  Thanks.

EDIT: As suggested I've included the code I'm using below.  At 5 iterations the noise on the signal is clearly apparent.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import special
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from scipy.signal import convolve 
from scipy.signal import gaussian

# Constants
B =   426400E-9 # tesla
R = 71723E3
Rkm = R / 1000.
Omega =  1.75e-4 #8.913E-4 # rads/s
period = (2. * np.pi / Omega) / 3600.   # Gets period in hours
Bj = 2.0 * B
mdot = 1000.
sigmapstar = 0.05


# Create rhoe array
rho0 = 5.* R 
rho1 = 100. * R 
rhoe = np.linspace(rho0, rho1, 2.E5) 


# Define flux function and z component of equatorial field strength
Fe = B * R**3 / rhoe
Bze = B * (R/rhoe)**3

def derivs(u, rhoe, p):
    """Computes the derivative"""

    wOmegaJ = u
    Bj, sigmapstar, mdot, B, R = p

    # Compute the derivative of w/omegaJ wrt rhoe (**Fe and Bjz have been subbed)
    dwOmegaJ = (((8.0*np.pi*sigmapstar*B**2 * (R**6)) / (mdot * rhoe**5)) \
    *(1.0-wOmegaJ) - (2.*wOmegaJ/rhoe))
    res = dwOmegaJ
    return res 


its = 5 # number of iterations to perform
i = 0
# Loop to iterate
while i < its:

    # Define the initial condition of rigid corotation
    wOmegaJ_0 = 1
    params = [Bj, sigmapstar, mdot, B, R]
    init = wOmegaJ_0

    # Compute numerical solution to Hill eqn
    u = odeint(derivs, init, rhoe, args=(params,))
    wOmega = u[:,0]


    # Calculate I_rho
    i_rho = 8. * np.pi * sigmapstar * Omega * Fe * ( 1. - wOmega)

    dx = rhoe[1] - rhoe[0]
    differential = np.gradient(i_rho, dx)
    jpara = 1. * differential / (4 * np.pi * rhoe * Bze )  
    jpari = 2. * B * para

    # Remove infinity and NaN values)
    jpari[~np.isfinite(jpari)] = 0.0 

    # Convolve to smooth curve 
    nw = 256
    std = 40
    window = gaussian(nw, std, sym=True)
    filtered = convolve(jpari, window, mode='same') /np.sum(window)
    jpari = filtered 

    # Pedersen conductivity as function of jpari
    sigmapstar0 = 0.05
    jstar = 0.01e-6
    jstarstar = 0.25e-6
    s1 = 0.1e6#0.1e6  # (Am^-2)^-1
    s2 = 9.9e6  # (Am^-2)^-1
    n = 8.

    # Calculate news sigmapstar. Realistic conductivity
    sigmapstarNew =  sigmapstar0 + 0.5 * (s1 + s2/(1 + (jpari/jstarstar)**n)**(1./n)) * (np.sqrt(jpari**2 + jstar**2) + jpari)
    sigmapstarNew = sigmapstarNew

    diff = np.abs(sigmapstar - sigmapstarNew) / sigmapstar  *  100
    diff = max(diff)

    sigmapstar = 0.5* sigmapstar + 0.5* sigmapstarNew  # Weighted averaging

    i += 1

    print diff

# Plot jpari
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.plot(rhoe/R, jpari * 1e6)
ax.axhline(0, ls=':')
ax.set_xlabel(r'$\rho_e / R_{UCD}$')
ax.set_ylabel(r'$j_{\parallel i} $ / $ \mu$ A m$^{-2}$')
ax.set_xlim([0,80])
ax.set_ylim(-0.01,0.01)
plt.locator_params(nbins=5)

plt.draw()
plt.show()
```

Comment: I agree that the derivative estimate is probably the culprit. You _might_ get a better result by computing your signal with a smaller time step and higher arithmetic precision. But I suspect that you may need to use a more stable way of computing your signal. There's not much point in filtering out the noise if the resulting signal diverges from what it's supposed to be. I assume your signal generation algorithm is essentially a numerical integration. If so, you may be able to use a better integration technique. But it's hard to say without seeing your current algorithm.

Comment: It's generally avoidable to use very large and/or very small numbers in sensitive numerical calculations. Is it possible to transform your equations to a dimensionless/rescaled form, where most numbers that appear are on the order of 1? If this is possible, this will surely improve accuracy (in terms of floating-point errors).

Comment: Also, did you check the magnitude of your noisy data? A low-pass filter *should* help with that, but if your numbers are already close to machine precision then there's nobody who can save you.

Comment: The more I keep looking at your derivative, the more I see a recipe for disaster. Your `dwOmegaJ` contains, among other things, `R**6` which is equal to around `3.1e37`. That is then multiplied by all sorts of large and small factors. [Disasters have happened due to much smaller issues](http://ta.twi.tudelft.nl/users/vuik/wi211/disasters.html).